# Need help to implement a parameter in function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple events on multiple divs, all work well except the var "i" which I can't pass in the parameter in the handleEvent function, to display the number of div, in the alert.

```js
['click', 'mouseover', 'mouseout'].forEach(function(e) {
  var aze = document.querySelectorAll('.aaa');
  for (var i = 0; i < aze.length; i++) {
    aze[i].addEventListener(e, handleEvent);
  }
});

function handleEvent(e) {
  if (e.type == "mouseover") {
    e.target.className = "underline";
  } else if (e.type == "mouseout") {
    e.target.className = "";
  } else if (e.type == "click") {
    alert("paragraphe " + i);
    e.target.className = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="aaa">This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p class="aaa">This is paragraph 2.</p>
<p class="aaa">This is paragraph 3.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Function#bind`.

```
['click', 'mouseover', 'mouseout'].forEach(function(e) {
    var aze = document.querySelectorAll('.aaa');
    for (var i = 0; i < aze.length; i++ ) {              
        aze[i].addEventListener(e, handleEvent.bind(null, i));
    }
});
function handleEvent(i, e) {
  //...
  console.log('index:', i, 'type:', e.type);
}
```

You could also return the event handler function from `handleEvent`.

```
['click', 'mouseover', 'mouseout'].forEach(function(e) {
    var aze = document.querySelectorAll('.aaa');
    for (var i = 0; i < aze.length; i++ ) {              
        aze[i].addEventListener(e, handleEvent(i));
    }
});
function handleEvent(i) {
    return function(e){
       //handle event
       console.log('index:', i, 'type:', e.type);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Martin No problem.

Comment: Done :) Sorry to be late

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that **returns** the handleEvent function:

```
function makeHandleEvent (i) {
    function handleEvent(e) {
        if (e.type == "mouseover") {
            e.target.className = "underline";
        }else if(e.type == "mouseout"){
            e.target.className = "";
        }else if(e.type == "click") {
            alert("paragraphe " + i );
            e.target.className = "";
        }
    }

    return handleEvent;
}
```

Now you can pass it the value of `i`:

```
aze[i].addEventListener(e, makeHandleEvent(i));
```